# Enabling toggle editing when loading layers form postgis in QGIS

Tags: postgis, pyqgis, query-layer

I'm trying to load layers from PostGIS using the code bellow:

```
uri = QgsDataSourceUri()
uri.setConnection(server, PORT, base, user, mdp)
root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
group = root.addGroup(groupname)
for element in table_list:
if element == "bpe":
    asql = """SELECT id,
                 geom, 
                 nom,   # primary Key
                 code, 
                 adresse, 
                 cp, 
                 ville, 
                 type_fonc,
                 etat, 
                 modele, 
                 reference, 
                 Proprietai,
                 gestionnai, 
                 date_de_cr, 
                 emprise 
           FROM  public.bpe 
           INNER JOIN public.bpe_projet AS bp ON bpe.nom = bp.nom_bpe 
           WHERE bp.nom_projet = '%s'""" % project
    uri.setDataSource('', '(' + asql + ')', 'geom','','nom')
    layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(), element, "postgres")
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer, False)
```

When the layers loaded into QGIS, the toggle editing is disabled.

While I'm using the code below, the toggle editing is enabled.

```
elif element == "support":
    asql = "nom_projet= '%s' " % project
    uri.setDataSource('public', element, GEOM, asql)
    layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(), element, "postgres")
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer, False)
```

What modification I need to do for the first code for enabling the toggle editing?

Comment: The difference is the JOIN in the first SQL query. From the point of QGIS it is a non editable view.

Comment: @Zoltan Thank you for your answer, so what I need to do in this case for getting the same thing to the second SQL i;e not a view?

Comment: Add data only from one postgis table to QGIS (without joining to other tables).

Comment: But here, I have to filter some data from the table bpe for example, so I need to the condition in where for getting what I wnat, not all the table bpe.

Comment: You can select rows with embedded select in where clause, it may help: SELECT id, ... FROM bpe WHERE nom in (SELECT nom_bpe FROM bpe_project WHERE nom_project = '%s')

Comment: Thank you Zoltan, but still not working because the toggle editing is disabled again, may be the problem came from  `uri.setDataSource('', '(' + asql + ')', 'geom','','nom')`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111746/discussion-between-nmokht97-and-zoltan).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for my question is below, hope that will help

```
uri = QgsDataSourceUri()
uri.setConnection(server, PORT, base, user, mdp)
root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
group = root.addGroup(groupname)
for element in table_list:
if element == "bpe":
    asql = "nom IN (SELECT nom_bpe FROM bpe_projet WHERE bpe_projet.nom_projet ='%s')" % project
    uri.setDataSource('public', element, 'geom', asql)
layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(), element, "postgres")
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer, False
```

Like this you have a filter and you can edit your layer.

Thank's to @Zoltan